# What is this service?

Tags: udp, scan

Fairly new to infosec and am going through a course on nmap. While scanning I found this and it looked interesting and was wondering if you all had any information on this?

This is the port,state and service in question.

```
464/udp   open|filtered kpasswd5
```

Comment: https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=464

Comment: Even though you discovered this service on an nmap course, the question itself has nothing to do with security. It is also easily looked up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact you're seeing this service and port suggests you may be scanning a Domain Controller, for which both UDP & TCP ports 464 are used by the Kerberos Password Change. 
This port in particular is used for changing/setting passwords against Active Directory.

Doing an nmap -A might help you identify which version is being run and could assist in helping you work out what type of attack it's vulnerable against.

On a side note, if you're like me and find it useful to know why that service exists, the one in question has a good read up [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-3321/intro-25/index.html).